# Negation of $R = \exists x \in \mathbb R :\left[(x^2 = (x+1)^2)\land({x^3 \in \mathbb Z})\right]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification

what is the negation of
$$R = \exists x \in \mathbb R :\left[(x^2 = (x+1)^2)\land({x^3 \in \mathbb Z})\right]$$

ATTEMPT

$$( \forall x \in  \mathbb R )\text{ }[(x^2 \neq (x+1)^2) \lor ({x^3 \notin \mathbb Z})]$$

Comment: If it weren't for the lack of parentheses on both the first formula and the second, it would be correct.

Comment: It looks like you have the right idea here.

Answer (score 5):

Well done, now that parentheses have been fixed. That is precisely the negation of the original statement.

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer. I am downvoting.

Comment: @user113609 Actually since the tag *solution verification* is obviously suited here, this is good enough to be an answer.